# Reactjs Dynamic Table with Headers and Subheaders and filling it with data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

I am creating a dynamic table in ReactJS which will include header and subheader and then a lot of data under those headings, which will also include search functionality on the basis of the role of the person that will come through a dropdown on the table.

[image]

In this image the table, first 4 columns will not have any header but after that there will be a heading and then the columns will be divided into those headers. it will also have search functionality according to the role that are there in the image in the form of tabs (AP/P , ADM, Agent). And the columns under those headers which are {"Standard","Actual","ACH% " } , these can also change according to the role.

My main challenge is that I am not able to configure the Json according to the data and looping it to push it into Table in ReactJs.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: You haven't defined what's the JSON structure you're using and didn't attach an example of your code (what you've already tried). I suggest you start by adding these, then we'll be able to assist you

Comment: I am actually starting to work on it .

Comment: I just want to know the structure of the json to be used and how it can be used to do create the table. Can you please give me any example for this structure?

Comment: This is the json:  
var table = { thead: [{ header: "A", subheaders: [ "A1", "A2" ] }, { header: "B", subheaders: [ "B1", "B2", "B3" ] }, { header: "C", subheaders: [ "C1", "C2", "C3" ] }] };